# error de sintaxis en la función de javascript

Tags: javascript

me ayudan a ver por qué me manda error la función?

```
var a = 10;

var b = 20;

var nombre = "miguel ";

var apellido = "moreno";

function saludar(a < b) {
    console.log (`hola ${nombre + apellido}`)
    
}
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 
saludar (a < b);
VM3007:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: saludar is not defined at <Anonymous>:1:1
```

Esperaba que al ver que los parámetros de la función se cumplían me escribiera en el navegador:

```
hola miguel moreno
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda visitar la sección [ask] si es tu primera vez en el sitio, por favor intenta formtear tu pregunta y explicar un poco mejor que es lo que quieres lograr así los demás podrán ayudarte

Comment: En la función se pasan parámetros, no expresiones, por ejemplo esto sería correcto: function saludar(a, b) y dentro preparas la lógica, eso sería incorrecto: function suma(a + b)

Comment: no entiendo por que la gente mete tantos negativos ... a las publicaciones web, que ganan ...

Comment: te recomiendo hacer el [tour] hay te ganas la primera medalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede usar `<` en la lista de parámetros. En su lugar, debes usar una expresión que evalúe a true o false.

Dentro de la función saludar, agregamos una condición `if` para verificar si la expresión `a < b` es verdadera o falsa, y luego imprimir un mensaje dependiendo si se cumple o no.

En la plantilla de cadena de texto para imprimir el saludo, corregí la interpolación para que el nombre y el apellido estén separados por un espacio en blanco.

Te muestro tu código modificado:

```js
var a = 10;
        var b = 20;
        var nombre = "miguel";
        var apellido = "moreno";
        
    //Aquí declaramos la función saludar
        function saludar(condicion) {
            if (condicion) {
                console.log(`hola ${nombre} ${apellido}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`adios ${nombre} ${apellido}`);
            }
        }
        
    //Aquí es donde hacemos la llama la función saludar
        saludar(a < b);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta si me funciono y aprendí el comando if ya que no sabia que existía (gracias otra vez)

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado, suerte en tu proyecto.
Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu función de JavaScript se debe a que estás tratando de usar una expresión booleana `(a < b)` como `parámetro` de la función saludar, lo cual no es válido.

La declaración de la función no puede incluir expresiones booleanas como parte de la definición de los parámetros o firma.

***hay varias soluciones, con diferentes grados de dificultad:***

***- Aqui un ejemplo basico:***

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var nombre = "miguel ";
var apellido = "moreno";

function saludar() {
    if (a < b) {
        console.log(`hola ${nombre + apellido}`);
    }
}

saludar();
```

***- otra forma con declaracion local y pasando parametros tambien basico:***

```js
let a = 10;
let b = 20;
let nombre = "miguel ";
let apellido = "moreno";


function saludar(a,b,nombre,apellido) {
    if (a < b) {
        console.log(`hola ${nombre + apellido}`);
    }
}

saludar(a,b,nombre,apellido);
```

***- Ahora tambien podemos pasar un objeto y simplificar nuestro metodo (Intermedio, iniciando algo de OOP):***

```js
let datos = {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    nombre: "miguel",
    apellido: "moreno"
};

function saludar({ a, b, nombre, apellido }) {
    if (a < b) {
        console.log(`¡Hola ${nombre} ${apellido}!`);
    }
}

saludar(datos);
```

***Nota:*** muy importante cuando pasamos un objeto podemos implementar las llaves `{}` en la recepcion de argumentos para extraer las propiedades del objeto y usarlas.

Answer (score 2):

El interprete no esperaba un `<` sino una definición de parámetros para que la función utilice.

Dentro de la función ( entre los `{ }` ) cuando loas parametros ( variables ) existen y tienen valor ahí si podés hacer la comparación:

Una opción es decirle que hay dos parámetros y hacer la comparación:

```
function saludar(a , b) {
  if (a < b)
    console.log (`hola ${nombre + apellido}`)
}
```

Otra opción es hacer la comparación por fuera:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var nombre = "miguel ";
var apellido = "moreno";

function saludar() {
  console.log (`hola ${nombre + apellido}`)
}

if (a < b) {
 saludar();
} else {
console.log (`no te saludo ${nombre + apellido}`)
}
```